# How to hide completely a QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a button followed by a `QGridLayout` full of widgets.
I want to show/hide `QGridLayout` at every button click, but reading documentation of `QGridLayout` I see there's no `show()`/`hide()` implementation, also no `setVisible()` method available.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of Qt you're using.  (I'm looking at the [4.4 documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qlayoutitem.html).)

I haven't tried this, but here are two ideas:

- `QGridLayout` inherits the function `QLayoutItem::widget()`.  If your layout is a widget, this will return a `QWidget*` on which you can call `show()` or `hide()`.
- If your `QGridLayout` is not a `QWidget`, you can nest it within a `QWidget`, and you can `show()` / `hide()` that widget instead.

Comment: I'm using 4.6.1, and I already tried that widget()->hide() method, but throwed a segment fault. Maybe I got something wrong

Comment: @clinisbut: Did you test the result of `widget()` to see if it's valid?  It may return `NULL` / `0`.

Answer (score 7):

Layouts only affect the size/position of the widgets added to them - for visibility (and anything else - event handling, focus, enable+disable) you care about the parent widget, as mentioned above. QLayout::parentWidget() gives you the widget which owns the layout, which you can then show and hide.

Comment: So you suggest to wrap the qlayout in a qwidget to be able to hide/show() isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on how Layouts work.  I haven't used them before, so I'm just guessing based on the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have multiple `QGridLayout` instances, only one should be visible based on the button that has been clicked. You can use a `QStackedWidget` for this:

> The QStackedWidget class provides a
>   stack of widgets where only one widget
>   is visible at a time.

Then, for each widget in the `QStackedWidget` you should associate a separate `QGridLayout`.

See the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstackedwidget.html) for more details